# Can the 2D plane be tessellated with a finite set of closed curves that have Geometric continuity > 1?

Tags: geometry, continuity, geometric-construction, tessellations

When I think of tessellating the 2D plane, all examples I can think of (squares, hexagons, rhombuses, polygonal stars...) have at least one point that is G1 continuous, even these fish:

[image]

Is it possible to tesselate the plane with a shape that has a higher geometric continuity than that? Alternatively, is there a proof that you can't?

Comment: G1 continuity appears to be a non-mathematical terminology. I think, what you mean is $C^1$. It is still unclear what your question  "Is it possible to tesselate the plane with a shape that has a higher geometric continuity than that?" means. Are you asking if it is possible to tile the plane by pairwise congruent domains with $C^1$-smooth boundary? Or do you mean if it is possible to time the plane by  pairwise congruent domains with nowhere $C^1$-boundaries?

Comment: G1 continuity refers to geometric continuity, which is a different concept than Analytic continuity.

Analytic continuity requires that the direction and magnitude of the limit agree. Geometric continuity only requires that the direction of the limits agree.

I am asking if there exists a finite set of shapes, where each shape has geometric continuity G>1 that tessellates the 2D plane.